# Как установить путь к стилям по умолчанию? Yii2

Tags: yii2

Не подключаются стили во вьюхах: `<link href="/css/1.css" rel="stylesheet">` -
 такой путь не видно. Приходится добавлять `<?= $asset->baseUrl ?>`.
Как это исправить?

Структура приложения такая:

[image]

Во вьюхе подключаю:

```
$asset = app\assets\AppAsset::register($this);
```

AppAsset:

```
class AppAsset extends \yii\web\AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@app/media2/';
    public $css = [
        'css/1.css',
        'css/theme-4-bootstrap.css',
        'css/vendor.css',
        'css/theme-4.css',
        'css/demo.css',
        'css/custom.css'
    ];
   ...................
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        'yii\web\YiiAsset', 
    ];
}
```

web.php:

```
'assetManager' => [
            // uncomment the following line if you want to auto update your assets (unix hosting only)
            //'linkAssets' => true,
            'forceCopy' => true, //перезапись файлов стилей
```

Answer (score 0):

В

```
public $sourcePath = '@app/media2/';
```

уберите последний слеш

```
public $sourcePath = '@app/media2';
```